# Do I have the guarantee that std::unique will keep the first element?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique, standards, stl-algorithm

Consider a sorted `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` based on comparison of the first element of pair.

Now assume that I apply:

```
std::unique(std::begin(v), 
            std::end(v), 
            [](const std::pair<int, int>& x, const std::pair<int, int>& y)
            {return x.first == y.first;});
```

Do I have the guarantee that `std::unique` will keep the first element of every equal ranges ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

> Eliminates all but the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements from the range [first, last) and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range.

[From here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)

The `BinaryPredicate` you have given just means that any element with `y` equal to the previous element `x` will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [The C++14 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) says in section 25.3.9 [alg.Unique] (emphasis mine):

> Effects: For a nonempty range, **eliminates all but the first element** from every consecutive group of equivalent elements referred to by the iterator i in the range [first + 1,last) for which the following conditions hold: *(i - 1) == *i or pred(*(i - 1), *i) != false.

The citation of the standard is important here because the usual Internet sources on this point give two different answers: en.cppreference.com does not give the guarantee, but cplusplus.com (cited by [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294207/ben) [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24052435/309334) has the guarantee.)